# Why such a simple BufWriter operation didn't work

Tags: rust-tokio

The following code is very simple. Open a file as a write, create a `BufWriter` using the file, and write a line of string.

The program reports no errors and returns an `Ok(10)` value, but the file just has no content and is empty.

```rust
#[tokio::test]
async fn save_file_async() {
    let path = "./hello.txt";
    let inner = tokio::fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .create(true)
        .write(true)
        //.truncate(true)
        .open(path)
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let mut writer = tokio::io::BufWriter::new(inner);
    println!(
        "{} bytes wrote",
        writer.write("1234567890".as_bytes()).await.unwrap()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need an explicit flush:

```rust
writer.flush().await.unwrap();
```